# How do i change a single value data into an array table in Laravel Jetstream vue stack?

Tags: vue.js, controller, laravel-9

I hv this configuration of Operating Unit. Inside the config, i got several data such as name, area, land, latitude, longtitude, license, expiry date and few others. But the problem here is, user suddenly said that, some Operating Unit will have multiple license. So far, everything else is single value, so rn i hv to change only the license n expiry date into array.

I hv tried few things but it doesn't change anything. I would like the data to be the same, and change only the way data is formatted. Maybe i tackled this issue wrongly, or maybe there's something i didn't noticed since i just started. But the system is a bit complex and it doesnt use a straightforward way as seen in youtube or documentation